# Extract particular string which appears in multiple lines in cell Pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, extract

I have to extract string which starts with "Year" and finishes with "\n", but for each line that appears in a cell in Pandas data frame.
Additionally, I want to remove \n at the end of cell.

This is data frame:

df

```
  Column1
  not_important1\nnot_important2\nE012-855 Year-1972\nE012-856 Year-1983\nnot_important3\nE012-857 Year-1977\nnot_important4\nnot_important5\nE012-858 Year-2012\n
  not_important6\nnot_important7\nE013-200 Year-1982\nE013-201 Year-1984\nnot_important8\nE013-202 Year-1987\n
  not_important9\nnot_important10\nE014-652 Year-1988\nE014-653 Year-1980\nnot_important11\nE014-654 Year-1989\n
```

This is what I want to get:

df

```
  Column1
  Year-1972\nYear-1983\nYear-1977\nYear-2012
  Year-1982\nYear-1984\nYear-1987
  Year-1988\nYear-1980\nYear-1989
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with this regex `r'Year.*?\\n'` to catch the substrings. Then create a string from the list of the found elements with `''.join` and then remove the last `\n` with `[:-2]` :

```
import re
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.findall('Year.*?\\n', x))[:-2])
```

Or, if after the 4 digits of the year there is always `\n`, you can do in this way:

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(re.findall('Year-\d\d\d\d', x)))
```

Comment: It says: NameError: name 're' is not defined. Should I install or import something?

Comment: Yes, `import re` which is the Regular expression library

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it seems logical. However, when I print(df), I got only indexes 0,1,2 - without the content of Column1. I wonder what I did wrong?

Comment: Apparently it didnt find any of the substrings. Is the df the same that you posted? or `Year` not capital letter for example?

Comment: I used the same df. The "Year" is present with the capital letter. I used this as df: df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['not_important1\nnot_important2\nE012-855 Year-1972\nE012-856 Year-1983\nnot_important3\nE012-857 Year-1977\nnot_important4\nnot_important5\nE012-858 Year-2012\n',
                            'not_important6\nnot_important7\nE013-200 Year-1982\nE013-201 Year-1984\nnot_important8\nE013-202 Year-1987\n', 'not_important9\nnot_important10\nE014-652 Year-1988\nE014-653 Year-1980\nnot_important11\nE014-654 Year-1989\n']})

Comment: What does It happen of you use this instead:`df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(re.findall('Year-\d\d\d\d', x)))` ?

Comment: Now it works for me. Sorry I was typing when you posted the last comment. Thank you.

Comment: And also works for the first solution that you proposed, but only if I remove "r" in front of 'Year.*?\\n'.

Comment: Yes, I've realized now that the problem was the `raw string`